# how to check using jsonpath if property exists with a given value

Tags: jsonpath

Hi this is a simple json

```
{"one": 335, "two": 331,"three": 65}
```

i need the json path to evaluate if a property has a value, example if exists "two":331

i tried this but it doesn't match.

```
$.two==331
```

what is the right expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there is any property in the given document with value 331 with this jsonpath expression: `$[?(@==331)]` But this will result an output like `[331]`. There is no chance to get the name of the matching property by using jsonpath only. You have to embed your expression into a script which supports jsonpath execution. Python does. Newer .NET Core based solutions (written with C# 9 and above) look also pretty simple.

Comment: in dotnet i first created a jobject then added it to jarray and checked the property with SelectToken method. bool exists== jarray.SelectToken("$[?(@.two==331)]")!=null;